# Where am I going wrong

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

So I am very new to Django and I am confused where am I going wrong. I am trying to create a simple calculator to calculate profit estimates. Here is what it shows in my HTML so far. Kind of confused where am I going wrong. Any help appreciated.

[image]

This the HTML file code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>

    {% block content %}
    <form action = "something" method = "post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value=Submit>
    </form>
    {% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

This is forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Calc

class Calculator(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Calc
        fields = ['gross_receivable', 'TDS', 'bank_charges', 'vendor_payable']
```

This is the models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Calc(models.Model):
    gross_receivable = models.IntegerField()
    TDS = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    bank_charges = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    vendor_payable = models.IntegerField()
```

This is the views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import Calc

    def something(request):
        form = Calc()
        context = {'form': form}
        return render(request, "calculator1.html", context)
```

Comment: You haven't asked a question, what is it doing that you dont expect?

Answer (score 0):

Your form name is Calculator but you are importing your model as form.

You should change

```
from .forms import Calc
```

to

```
from .forms import Calculator
```

and in the something function

```
form = Calculator()
```